# .htaccess for multiple laravel instalations on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, shared-hosting

I have multiple laravel Projects in a single shared hosting account.
Domain 1 owns the root folder, which has index.php file linked to Laravel project1, and a .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)\ ([^/]+)/(.*)/? /$1$2/$3/ [L]
```

Domain 2 points to a sub folder called project2 which is a clone to project1 that reads another mysql database.

Sadly, when using domain2, any subdomain returns internal server error. As far as I can tell the problem is related to the .htaccess file forcing the url to be processed by index.php from project1 instead of project2.

What can I do to avoid said behavior?

Answer (score 0):

**Wokring solution:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain2.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ project2/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_]+)\ ([^/]+)/(.*)/? /$1$2/$3/ [L]
```